# use static url in url routing yii2

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

I have an old website, now I have written it with new version of yii framework and I want change the urls, but because of SEO problems I want to keep my old urls.
Now when the user enters `www.mysite.pre/car/details/10908` I want application renders `www.mysite.pre/site/show_detail/10908` how could I handle it in yii2 Routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have got this action in your SiteController class

```
public function actionShow_detail($id) {}
```

Add this in your configuration file:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName'  => false,
        'rules'           => [
            // ...
            'car/details/<id:\d+>' => 'site/show_detail',
        ],
    ],
],
```

More details and information about Yii 2 routing can be found in ["Routing and URL Creation"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html) section of [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html).